# Plant identification and toxicity

Tags: species-identification, botany, poison

What type of plant this is and is it poisonous (and, if so, in what quantities)? 
The pictures were taken at Gullane Bay, Scotland. The plant is widely present in that region.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should try Google search by image. Its pretty handy when you dunno what you're looking at.

Comment: @user79161 I’ve tried but results are not conclusive. I reckon the pictures are not the best and algorithms fail to properly differentiate plant from the background and surroundings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [common sea buckthorn, *Hippophae rhamnoides*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippophae_rhamnoides). The blueish leaves and the orange berries are unmistakable.

It occurs mainly in coastal regions, but is also cultivated throughout the world. The berries are processed to all kinds of food.
In their natural habitat in Northwestern Europe, the berries serve as a food source for migrating birds that fly from Scandinavia to the UK or the Netherlands. However, because the berries are often rotting and contain alcohol in september, sometimes drunk birds can be observed.

Comment: Thank you very much for this comprehensive and informative answer.